# Value of performance counter is strange

Tags: c#, .net

I used the following code to determine the total CPU usage of the computer.

```
private int getCPUUsage()
{
    PerformanceCounter cnt = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    return (int)cnt.NextValue();
}
```

But, the CPU usage of the task manager is about 20%, but the output value of function is mostly 0, sometimes 100.

The odd point is that when I put a MessageBox in the middle of a function, the value of MessageBox is wrong, but the return value is correct.

```
private int getCPUUsage()
{
    PerformanceCounter cnt = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    MessageBox.Show(cnt.NextValue().ToString()); //Just 0
    return (int)cnt.NextValue(); //Right Value
}
```

So I ran `cnt.NextValue()` twice instead of `MessageBox`, but the result was the same as the original code.
**How do I get the `PerformanceCounter`'s CPU usage normally?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first value will always be 0 because there's nothing to compare to.

You have to run it more times to get the comparison. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx):

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the
>   first read operation returns 0.0. Resetting the performance counter
>   properties to specify a different counter is equivalent to creating a
>   new performance counter, and the first read operation using the new
>   properties returns 0.0. The recommended delay time between calls to
>   the NextValue method is one second, to allow the counter to perform
>   the next incremental read.